# Can you install a office app add-in written in JavaScript on OS X for Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, macos, ms-office

I recently came across the office API for JavaScript, and downloaded a github project to try it out, but I can't seem to find any documentation for how to add it to Excel on OS X.

[Here is the project I cloned.](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JS-CollegeBudgetTracker) The instructions work on a Windows machine, but not on my macbook.

Comment: it seems this is for Microsoft excel, not just any excel

Comment: I'm not aware of another Excel. My question is directed at Microsoft Excel.

Comment: [This page](https://blogs.office.com/2015/09/28/whats-new-in-office-2016-for-developers/) suggests that Office for Mac only supports add-ins for Outlook and not for any other Office programs

Comment: Thanks @barrowc, I looked around a lot, and found a lot of things that would have made me believe that this was possible.

Comment: The roadmap table on [this page](http://dev.office.com/blogs/office-js-public-preview) suggests Q1 of calendar year 2016 for the JavaScript API for Excel and Word to be available on Office for Mac

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but hope it may help someone seeking for information.

On a MAC, unless you have windows installed, you won`t be able to use Visual Studio, so you're left with two options for Office.js Add-ins development:

- **Using Napa**.You main find instructions on: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-an-office-add-in-with-napa
- **Using any editor** (I've been using Visual Studio Code and it works fine). You may find instructions on: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/get-started/create-an-office-add-in-using-any-editor

Using the information on these links, you shall be able to get any add-in for Office working on Mac. Still, it is important to check the documentation on dev.office.com for features supported on each product/platform.

At this moment, one main limitation on Mac (on comparison with Windows version) is that Add-In Commands are not supported, which means that you will not be able to customize the Ribbon UI, but you will still be able to create a satisfactory design and deliver a great user experience by using Task Panes.